# Python buildpack and Playwright dependencies

Tags: python, google-cloud-run, buildpack, playwright-python

I have a Python app that depends on Playwright (requirements.txt). The Playwright installation instructions [state that you need to download the browsers](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro#:%7E:text=Install%20the%20required%20browsers%3A) after installing the module.

When I build my app with `gcr.io/buildpacks/builder`, the Playwright module is correctly installed (because the python builder calls `pip` with `requirements.txt`) but the browsers are not installed.
As soon as the app runs, Playwright complains that the browsers are missing, and that I should run `playwright install` (and also, install dependencies).

I would like the builder to run `playwright install` to make the complete image. Is this possible? What are my options here?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I ended up building it with a custom dockerfile @nesp